# Comparing results of one group to mean result of several groups with unequal sample sizes

Tags: chi-squared-test, mean, unbalanced-classes

I need to compare results of one nation on several variables with the mean result of other nations that are participants in same research. Normally, the test would be a chi-squared or t-test (depending on variable compared). But the sample sizes of other nations vary, with some countries having 3 or 4 times more participants than others. I am aware that direct comparison would thus not be with the mean results of other nations, but mean results of all other participants. What can be done to get the relevant comparison with the mean results of other nations?

Comment: Is there reason to believe that the other nations all have the same mean? If not, what are you after exactly?

Comment: sorry if i am crytptic as english is not my first language. for example i need to compare  one country teacher participation in some activity average participation of all other countries teacher in same activity.as i am using spss i would go wit usual chi square but i as other countries are not same siye in number of participants using chi square with two group-main country compared to rest imo would not be valid as countries with higher samplkes would skew results.any way of overcoming it?

Comment: Fair enough, but are all other countries the same? If teacher participation in country A is 60%, & in B is 40%, what happens if participation in C is 50%? Is that 'the same' or different? What if C is 40%, is it then 'the same as other countries' or not?

Comment: no, other countries are not same in percent of participation.if they have for example B- 20%,C-30%,D-40% i would like it to be compared with their average which is 30% but as chi square in spss is as far as i know working with individual cases it would take number of participants in calculation so if some nation is higher in participants it would be skewed in its way for example if group/nation d is 40% in participation but 3 times higher in number than other gorups means would be closer to 40% than 30%.

Comment: its probably simple but i cant relay it.tnx on effort.really apreciate it.

Comment: ok,this is probably quite embarassing i see one can use weights in spps which would semingly fix problem with unequal sample sizes. problem is can with rationally i afterfward use chi square and t test in relation to sample i want to compare with and others which are now equlalised using weights?

Comment: TRy first to graph your data! (and maybe show us)